# Duplicated tasks after time change

Tags: python, timezone, task, celery, celery-task

I don't know exactly why, but I am getting duplicated tasks. I thing this may be related with time change of the last weekend (The clock was delayed for an hour in the system).

The first task should not be executed, since I say explicitly `hour=2`. Any idea why this happens?

```
[2017-11-01 01:00:00,001: INFO/Beat] Scheduler: Sending due task every-first-day_month (app.users.views.websites_down)
[2017-11-01 02:00:00,007: INFO/Beat] Scheduler: Sending due task every-first-day_month (app.users.views.websites_down)
```

---

```
from celery.schedules import crontab

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'every-first-day_month': {
        'task': 'app.users.views.websites_down',
        'schedule': crontab(hour=2, minute=0, day_of_month=1),
    }
}

CELERY_TIMEZONE = "Europe/Lisbon"
```

Comment: The clock change in `Europe/Lisbon` happened on October 29th, not November 1st.  Therefore, the issue is not likely related to DST.

Comment: @MattJohnson, I didn't say the clock change happened today, Only the issue.

Comment: Sure.  Sorry, I don't have any ideas.  Your code looks right to me.

Comment: you could do an experiment by changing your system datetime?

Comment: @georgexsh I think the problem was solved by delete celery schedule file and compile a new one. At least it seems working correctly now.

Comment: IIRC celery beats use monotonic clock internally, so sys time change wont be a problem.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue all of a sudden after years of using celery. @anvd when you say you deleted the file was that done locally?

Comment: @zerohedge This was a bug with redis. I have replaced it with rabbitmq