# Celery + Amazon SQS - Tasks performed twice after the last Daylight Saving Time Change

Tags: django, celery, amazon-sqs

On the last Sunday I found the tasks performed twice.
This has been a problem especially for mass emails sent twice.

What is the problem?

Another question, same issue, but no answer:
[Duplicated tasks after time change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47057983/duplicated-tasks-after-time-change)

**My celery config file**:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os

from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproj.settings_prod')

app = Celery('myproj')

# Using a string here means the worker doesn't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))


app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'mass-email1': {
        'task': 'myproj.myapp.tasks.send_email1',
        'schedule': crontab(hour=8, minute=30, day_of_week=1), # Executes every Monday morning at 8:30am
    }
}
```

The timezone set in `settings.py` is `TIME_ZONE = 'America/New_York'`.

**Celery packages**:

```
celery==4.1.1
django_celery_beat==1.1.1
django_celery_results==1.0.1
```

Comment: Which version of celery are you using?

Comment: @2ps I'm using Celery 4.1.1

Comment: @2ps This seems a common issue due to a lack of support of DST changes. It seems now fixed with the latest version. I'll install v4.2 https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/1604